# The search table in my Sqlite database won't work

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to app creating and for some reason my app won't open a table called "Full Book" which I was going to used in an activity to search using a "Material Search Bar". So every time I install the app on my physical device and try to open the search activity it crashes showing the following error message:

```
Process: uk.co.crystalclearlanguage.httpwww.dyagetmedoc, PID: 31912
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.crystalclearlanguage.httpwww.dyagetmedoc/uk.co.crystalclearlanguage.httpwww.dyagetmedoc.Main2Activity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: FullBook (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Phrase FROM FullBook
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such table: FullBook (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Phrase FROM FullBook)
    #################################################################
```

the really weird thing is however, when I use another activity that looks in the same database for another table and then try to run the search function it works perfectly.

Here is my database helper for the search function:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME="DoYouGetMeDoc.db";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;
    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

    public List<Items> getFullBook(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqliteSelect={"Phrase","Description","Example", "Chapter"};
        String tableName="FullBook";
        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqliteSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
        List<Items> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Items items = new Items();
                items.setPhrase(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phrase")));
                items.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                items.setExample(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Example")));
                items.setChapter(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Chapter")));
                results.add(items);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> getPhrases(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqliteSelect={"Phrase"};
        String tableName="FullBook";
        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqliteSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                results.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phrase")));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;

    }

    public List<Items> getPhrasesbyPhrase(String phrase)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        String[] sqliteSelect={"Phrase","Description","Example","Chapter"};
        String tableName="FullBook";
        qb.setTables(tableName);
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqliteSelect,"Phrase like ?",new String[]{"%"+phrase+"%"},null,null,null);
        List<Items> results = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Items items = new Items();
                items.setPhrase(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phrase")));
                items.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description")));
                items.setExample(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Example")));
                items.setChapter(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Chapter")));
                results.add(items);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Main2Activity (Search Activity):

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SearchAdapter adapter;
    MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
    List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();
    Database database;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyler_search);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        materialSearchBar = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        database = new Database(this);
        materialSearchBar.setHint("Search");
        materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
        loadSuggestionList();
        materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String search:suggestList)
                {
                    if (search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                        suggest.add(search);
                }
                materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
                if (!enabled)
                    adapter = new SearchAdapter(getBaseContext(),database.getFullBook());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
                startSearch(text.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {


            }
        });

        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getFullBook());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void startSearch(String text) {
        adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getPhrasesbyPhrase(text));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void loadSuggestionList() {
        suggestList = database.getPhrases();
        materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i= new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

Update:
the stack definitely says that the "DoYouGetMeDoc.db" database has been opened.

If it helps here is the search adapter/viewholder:

```
class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView phrase;
    public TextView decription;
    public TextView example;
    public TextView chapter;

    public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        phrase = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Phrase);
        decription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Description);
        example = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Example);
        chapter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Chapter);
    }
}

public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Items> items;

    public SearchAdapter(Context context, List<Items> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View itemview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new SearchViewHolder(itemview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder searchViewHolder, int i) {
        searchViewHolder.phrase.setText(items.get(i).getPhrase());
        searchViewHolder.decription.setText(items.get(i).getDescription());
        searchViewHolder.example.setText(items.get(i).getExample());
        searchViewHolder.chapter.setText(items.get(i).getChapter());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Once again. Any help and guidance would be very much appreciated especially since this is the last piece of the app that needs to work correctly.

Comment: show your database creation code snippet

Comment: I don't know what that is. I created the Database in DB browser for SQLite.

Comment: The exception says no such table FullBook.
check spelling and case of the table that you create
Moreover it caused by  missing database. check if your database created successfully before trying to insert or select data

Comment: I have but what really confusing me is that its just this one table, the other tables can be found and used perfectly. The really weird thing is when I uninstall the app on my device and then reinstall it, if I open one of the other tables first and then open the FullBook Table it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and I was missing an "instance" in my SQLiteAssetHelper Class. So I added the following:

```
 private static Database instance;

    public static Database getInstance(Context context){
        if (null == instance){
            instance = new Database(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

and added the following to my MainActivity.Java in the "OnCreate" method:

```
 Database.getInstance(this);
```